# ajax button with jquery for file download

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket

I have use wicket, ajax , jquery. On form (this has two fields for dates) submit, user gets file download popup. As it takes time I have spinner to display the processing, this works on ajax and jquery. 
Now issue is when I use normal wicket submit button though there is no spinner but the report download thing works fine. But when I use ajaxbutton the spinner comesup but there is no report open/save popup.

Following code works fine and gives open/save popup, though this does not show spinner as there is no ajax action

```
add(new SubmitLink("runReport") {

  *//**
   * 
   *//*
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 10011L;

  *//**
   * 
   *//*
  @Override
  public void onSubmit() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    map.put("reportStartDate", formatter.format(getReportStartDate()));

    // Add a day to the end date to include the date entered by the user.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(getReportEndDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    map.put("reportEndDate", formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
    generateReport(map,"ecommerceReport.rptdesign");
  }   
}
.add(RelativePathPrefixHandler.RELATIVE_PATH_BEHAVIOR)
);
```

following code shows spinner as its ajax, but there is no open/save popup

```
AjaxButton runReportButton = new AjaxButton("runReport", this) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10008L;

    @Override
    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        map.put("reportStartDate", formatter.format(getReportStartDate()));

        // Add a day to the end date to include the date entered by the user.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(getReportEndDate());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        map.put("reportEndDate", formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
        generateReport(map,"ecommerceReport.rptdesign");
        target.addComponent(form);
    }
};

runReportButton.add(RelativePathPrefixHandler.RELATIVE_PATH_BEHAVIOR);
runReportButton.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onmouseup", "showPopup();"));

add(runReportButton);
```

even following code does not work:

```
add(new AjaxFallbackButton("runReport", this) {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        map.put("reportStartDate", formatter.format(getReportStartDate()));

        // Add a day to the end date to include the date entered by the user.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(getReportEndDate());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        map.put("reportEndDate", formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
        generateReport(map,"ecommerceReport.rptdesign");
        target.addComponent(form);
    }
});
```

any help, what I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

This solution from the Wicket wiki should work for you - it can initiate a download on any sort of Ajax request:

<s>https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html</s>

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow

Comment: That link has died. :\

Comment: I added the new link. Apparently the Apache wiki moved.